# window.location does not redirect on empty page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm generating a page to fetch some variables and quickly redirect with them.
But the redirect is not executed.
This is the complete page rendered in my browser:

```
<HTML><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<head><LINK REL='stylesheet' TYPE='text/css' HREF='css/style.css' NAME='style'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
<title></title>
</head>

<script>

function get_init_values()
{
    //document.write("Hi");

    $clientWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    $clientHeight =  document.body.clientHeight;

    window.location="?page=init&clientwidth="+$clientWidth+"&clientheight="+$clientHeight;
    return false;

}</script>
<script>get_init_values();</script>
</HTML>
```

but when i uncomment the document.write statement the redirect executes as desired. What fundamental understanding am I missing here?
 I have tested this with IE, firefox and IPhone Safari with the same results.

Edit! 
The browser i just blank.
Removed the return in :
     return get_init_values();
which where just added for testing. No difference.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Nope! Just a blank page.

Comment: I get `Syntax Error: Illegal return statuement`. Why do you have a `return` on that line?

Comment: It's the same without. Just added it for testing purposes. I'll remove it.

Comment: You might be in an infinite loop. By checking the `location.search` string, I am able to short-circuit it and get it to run. http://jsfiddle.net/7jDn7/

Comment: See here for the URL shown: http://jsfiddle.net/7jDn7/2/ Note that re-running it with `Run` button in jsFiddle does not run it correctly, you have to reload the whole page.

Comment: No, I am not in a loop. As I say, I can make it redirect if I output data with the document.write function. Then my server will take the parameters and do other stuff, i.e. not loop.

Comment: Then it's on your server. I can get what you show to work. If it's PHP, it sounds like a parse error (blank white screen).

Comment: @idris Sorry, misunderstood what yoou meant by console. I really am a rookie. Yes, there was an error about non existing document.body. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Without mistakes you wouldn't learn. So your answer is solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code placed at the top of the page or the bottom? I'm thinking there's nothing rendered in the doc before it runs so it hits null and doesn't work. If you put it to the bottom of the page or had a node in the document to start with I think it should work then.

- Edit: You need a body element. Then put the script tags just inside the end `</body>` tag. The reason it doesn't work at the moment is because there is nothing within the document to get the ClientWidth/height from and when Null comes back for that it stops the script executing because there is an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null"

Comment: The complete page source are (now) showed. As you are suggesting there are nothing rendered as long as I do not uncomment the document.write funtcion. In that case it works! Is that the soloution, empty pages does not redirect?

Comment: After the end of the `</body>` tag? Like `</body><script>...`? That's not valid. It also won't make a difference.

Comment: you have no body tag so therefore no document to get a width or height of I reckon. (what's with the down vote btw, seems harsh?)

Comment: the invalid comment is fair, but if there's no nodes and no body tag I dont think it will be able to get any information from the document. I suggest a body tag, and a node (could be set to display none even) within it

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem, which is that the script is not getting run. If the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` are null, it will not prevent the page rest of the script running, it will only cause the values to be empty in the URL. This should be a comment under the question.

Comment: But if the script loads before the document and is finding null for information from the document an uncaught error shows up and stops the script from completing? (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null )

Comment: Alright, that's true. I didn't downvote you, sorry. The OP claims there's no errors in the console however, so if that can be believed, that seems to indicate it's not related.

Comment: Yes of course! Stupid me. Thought I had a relevant question. But the question was: Why doesnt my script work? Answer: Check the error log, stupid", well I learned something anyway.

Comment: @user3785903 - When somebody asks "anything in the console?", they are asking if you've looked at the browser's Javascript console. This is why so many times the OP is not believed when they claim to have properly debugged before asking the question. `;)`

Comment: @Jared. Right, sorry, as I told idris. Sorry sorry.